# jQuery post not working, data not defined

Tags: jquery, post

Trying to execute this:

```
function getReport(name) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "reportAjax.php",
        data: "name="+ name,
        success: function(data){
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);                
        }
    }); 
    alert(data);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    getReport('mobileDevicesBreakdown_30days');
});
```

I'm getting `data is not defined`

reportAjax.php is definitely available and always return something (even if the variables that are sent to it - currently `name` is incorrect or missing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `alert(data);` inside the success callback:

```
function getReport(name) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "reportAjax.php",
        data: "name="+ name,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);                
        }
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.ajax is an asynchronous method, so your `alert(data)` should be in the success part of the `.ajax`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to alert the data it needs to be within your success call

```
function getReport(name) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "reportAjax.php",
        data: "name="+ name,
        success: function(data){
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);                
            alert(data);
        }
    }); 

}
```